# concatenate a string and use it as part of the API Name for a field

Tags: apex

say i have a string that's dynamically assigned a prefix value.  i have a field called Upper_mechanical__c on the product2 object

For example

```
    List<parentObject> parentsToUpdate = new List<parentObject >();
string prefix = '';
//stuff happens
prefix = 'Upper_'
for(product2 pr: productArray){
    parentObject pa = new parentObject();
    pa.Id = pr.parentObject__c;
    if(some logic on the product2 values true){
    pa.prefix +'mechanical__c' = 25; 
    }
parentsToUpdate(pa); 
}
```

update parentsToUpdate;

How would i get that to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the SObject class `put` method

```
pa.put(prefix+'mechanical__c',25);
```